# Migration error on github actions with Django

Tags: django, continuous-integration, github-actions

I’m having trouble getting github actions to work with a django app. When I try to run migrations it fails, though if I install it as a new app on my computer the migrations run fine.
I’m brand new to github actions so I don’t really know what I’m doing, but I’ve been struggling with this for a bit today and figured I’d ask.

Here is my actions file: https://gist.github.com/pjhoberman/8333df201176bfc00e506ed7d8b4977a#file-django-yml-L52 - it’s failing at the highlighted line 52.

And the error is cumbersome and in full here: https://gist.github.com/pjhoberman/8a8ebd9838a9901e1c9929c219549f50

But is basically this:

```
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "listings_category" does not exist
 ...ory"."slug", "listings_category"."parent_id" FROM "listings_...
```

Comment: You're performing a DB query on initialization of your app in `ProductForm` - `choices = get_category_tree()`. You shouldn't do this

Comment: Interesting. I'll move it around. It works on my machine but not on github actions, which is weird, but, I'll try it!

Comment: @IainShelvington that worked! Thanks